# When is it optimal to dip two levels of Barbarian into this human variant fighter build?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, multi-classing, fighter, barbarian

I'm possibly going to play a variant human fighter in my next campaign with the GWM feat at level 1. I'm going to specialize Champion and I'm not sure when I should go for reckless attacks. **Should I do it before level 5 or after?**

**I'm either leaning towards fighter 3/barbarian 2 or fighter 5/barbarian 2**. My thoughts are this:

If I go fighter 3/barbarian 2, I get access to very early GWM + improved crits + reckless attacks. However, I am sacrificing the extra attack for two levels, which could possibly hamper my damage output for quite a large number of fights as leveling gets harder.

Comment: This question will probably get flagged as too opinion based, it would probably help if you rephrased it to listing pro's/con's of the 2 options.

Comment: A metric to judge the best option would help as well. Are you looking for max DPR? Best burst damage? Something else?

Comment: My plan was to go Sentinel level 4, so I suppose that I am looking for optimal burst damage in this case.

Comment: @BlueStork increasing your Str would give you much better DPR and more reliably than any feat

Comment: I think the question is fine after the edit.

Answer (score 17):

## Fighter 5/barbarian 2

One attack with Advantage is worse than two without, unless you have Sneak Attack*.

### Damage comparison

In both cases, you roll 2d20:

- If neither is high enough to hit, the result is the same
- If only one is high enough, the result is still the same
- If both would hit, 2 attacks do twice as much damage

As you can see, Advantage is identical in some cases, clearly worse in others, but never better.

### Reckless Attack is not free

Providing Advantage yourself is quite a steep price

### Other sources of Advantage exist

If your enemy is *prone*, *restrained* or provides Advantage for any other reason, your two attacks just got that much better. In the other case you DPR does not improve, you just don't provide Advantage.

**tl;dr:**  *Even if a 2nd level barbarian always had Advantage and without a cost, Fighter 5 would still have better DPR than Fighter 3/Barbarian 2*

---

*If one of your allies is standing next to the target, two attacks are better than Advantage on one, *even if* you have Sneak Attack

Answer (score 7):

To confirm [Andras's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/103998/23064), here's the damage per round comparing both paths up to 7th-level:

\begin{array}{r|ll}
\text{Character-level} & \text{Fgt3/Barb2} & \text{Fgt5} \\
\hline
1st & 7.883\bar{3} & 7.883\bar{3} \\
2nd & 7.883\bar{3} & 7.883\bar{3} \\
3rd & 8.3000 & 8.3000 \\
4th & 9.000 & 9.7667 \\
5th & 15.058 & 19.53\bar{3} \\
6th & 17.1567 & 21.13\bar{3} \\
7th & 34.313\bar{3} & 34.313\bar{3}
\end{array}

**Assumptions:**

- 60% chance to hit, regardless of strength. Increased to 65% when the ASI is taken at Fighter 4
- +2 strength at 4th-level
- Always using Great Weapon Master
- No Advantage from external sources

---

From a pure DPR stand-point, the Fighter 5 hands-down wins across all levels up to 7th.

Comment: I am assuming the OP is going fighter 3 first then either (a) barb 1, or (b) fighter 4 (hence the same numbers for the first 3 levels). F3B1 is slightly higher because rage adds +2 damage, ASI only +1. I agree +1 to hit is strong, but also assume that creatures increase AC as they level. I'll try to calculate again later with the increased hit chance